# EF - One to one optional relationship + SQL Server cascade

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, one-to-one

On SQLServer:

Table: FinanceiroLancamento

Id
Name
IdFinanceiroLancamentoCaixa
IdFinanceiroLancamentoBanco

Table: FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa

Id
Money

On EF - Code First for "FinanceiroLancamento":

```
        Property(p => p.Name)
            .IsRequired();

        HasOptional(p => p.FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.IdFinanceiroLancamentoCaixa);
```

On EF - Code First for "FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa":

```
        Property(p => p.Money)
            .HasPrecision(15, 2)
            .IsRequired();
```

My SQLServer relationship:

ALTER TABLE FinanceiroLancamento ADD CONSTRAINT [FinanceiroLancamento_003_FKEY] FOREIGN KEY ([IdFinanceiroLancamentoCaixa]) REFERENCES FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

So in the source code I can do:

var money = financeiroLancamento.FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa.Money:

The problem in my relationship is that when I delete "FinanceiroLancamento" it´s not deleting "FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa". But if I delete "FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa" it´s delete "FinanceiroLancamento".

I want the opposite, I would like to delete "FinanceiroLancamento" and it´s delete "FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa". How can I do it?

(I would like to continue with EF navigating from FinanceiroLancamento to FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa)

Thanks.

Best regards,

Wilton Ruffato Wonrath

Answer (score 0):

This is very strangely named. I'm not very fit in EF, but I gather that you want many (or zero or one) FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa records for each FinanceiroLancamento record. The normal way to do this in SQL would have an Id column in both tables plus a "IdFinanceiroLancamento" column in the FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa table.

Then you would define the foreign key as

```
ALTER TABLE FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa_FinanceiroLancamento
FOREIGN KEY (IdFinanceiroLancamento) 
REFERENCES FinanceiroLancamento(Id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Then, when you delete the FinanceiroLancamento record, the cascade deletes also the FinanceiroLancamentoCaixa record(s).

Comment: TToni, this case that you sad works fine thinking just in SQL Server, but I'm not able to apply this on EF.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237089/ef-one-to-one-relationship

I'm trying to find a workaround. 

Thanks.